# Angular 4 - CanActivate check component being route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, canactivate

In CanActivate is there a way to check which component is being route/requested by the user for authentication purpose. So instead of checking the url as i am doing below, i would like to do something like if(route.component instanceof MyComponent).

I am implementing role based access with ability to config each role to have different access level (view,edit etc..) for different component. So the easiest thing I thought would be to get current component being route and then check access level for that component rather than creating different AuthGard for each component.

i am trying to do this by check url but its casing problem when there is parameter included in url.

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot) {       
            let ac = this.auth.getAccessConfig();
            switch (state.url) {
                case '/site':
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.Site && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.View);
                case '/site/new':
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.Site && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.Modify);
                case '/site/:id': ***//this doesn't work as :id could be anything***
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.SiteDetail && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.View);
                case '/reports/milestone':
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.MilestoneReport && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.View);
                case '/reports/audit':
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.AuditReport && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.View);
                case '/reports/schedule':
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.ReportScheduler && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.View);
                case '/importer':
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.Import && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.View);
                case '/reports':
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.SiteReport && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.View);
                case '/admin/users':
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.User && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.View);
                case '/admin/tables':
                    return ac.some(x => x.moduleID == AccessModulesEnum.ReferenceTable && x.permissionID == AccessPermissionEnum.View);
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Another question: is it possible to call AuthGard with parameter from Routes configuration like { path: 'site/:id', component:SiteDetail,canActivate:[(callCustomeAuthGard('SiteDetailComponent')]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have found solution for the above problem using **route.routeConfig.path** to check for route path instead of url which will be like 'site/:id' instead of 'site/2'.

But would like to if there is any better way of doing role base authentication as above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `route.component`? [According to the docs](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot#component), this should contain the component class being routed to.

If so, the activation guard could ask the component class which permissions it requires.

Comment: yes, i did but don't now how do i check/compare it what component is it. (route.component instanceof MyComponent) does work.

Comment: Try `route.component == MyComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Your ActivatedRouteSnapshot (the route parameter you use in the canActivate function) contains the component.

So you can just use:

```
if (route.component === MyComponent) {
  // Do something
}
```